# Is it possible change the fragment when listview click

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to change the fragment when listview item clicked under Bottom navigation activity

But I have not idea how to write the OnClickListener

Anyone can provide some hints or tell me what wrong in this program?

Here is the program

And thank you for spend the time to view my program

Thank you very much

```
package com.example.campus.ui.campus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.c.MainActivity;
import com.example.c.R;
import com.example.c.database.campus.CampusData;
import com.example.c.ui.campusInformation.CampusInformationActivity;
import com.example.c.ui.campusInformation.CampusInformationFragment;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CampusListLayoutAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<CampusData> campusList = new ArrayList<CampusData>();
    private int resourceViewID;
    private Context context;

    private Context mContext;

    static class ViewHolder{
        LinearLayout llCampusCard;
        TextView tvCampusName;
        TextView tvCampusAddress;
        ImageView ivCampusImage;
    }

    public CampusListLayoutAdapter(Context c, List<CampusData>  campusList){

        context = c;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.campusList = campusList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return campusList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        mContext = viewGroup.getContext();
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_campus, null);


        if(view != null){
            holder.tvCampusName = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCampusName);
            holder.tvCampusAddress = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCampusAddress);
            holder.ivCampusImage = view.findViewById(R.id.ivCampusImage);

            holder.tvCampusName.setText(campusList.get(i).name);
            holder.tvCampusAddress.setText(campusList.get(i).address);

            String image = campusList.get(i).image;
            resourceViewID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(image, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            holder.ivCampusImage.setImageResource(resourceViewID);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    



                }

            });



            return view;
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create an interface in your adapter class.

```
public interface Callbacks {
    void onItemClick(YourObject object, int position); // arguments as per the requirement
}
```

change your constructor of adapter as

```
Callbacks callback;
public CampusListLayoutAdapter(Context c, List<CampusData>  campusList, Callbacks callback){
 .....
 this.callback = callback;
}
```

Now in your onClick() use..

```
callback.onItemClick(yourClickedItem, position)
```

then pass an anonymous or simply implement interface in your activity.

```
adapter = new CampusListLayoutAdapter(context, list, new CampusListLayoutAdapter.Callbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Alert_bean alert, int position) {
                // do what you want here in activity like changing fragment or view updates
            }
        });
```